# How can I bind click event to an angular2 template interpolation?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to bind click event to an interpolation? because when I am trying to execute the following code I get the following

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):

Error: Template parse errors:

Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 7 in [upload({{config.fileLocation}})]

this is the template where we have faulty interpolation,

```
  <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="upload({{config.fileLocation}})">Upload</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
```

and this is the angular component which is desired to be executed.

```
  upload(location = "/tmp/") {
  this.loader.open();

  const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
  if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileBrowser.files[0]);
    formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({
      "method": "filesystem.put",
      "params": [location + fileBrowser.files[0].name, { "mode": "493" }]
    }));

    this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint, formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.loader.close();
        this.snackBar.open("your files are uploaded", 'close', { duration: 5000 });
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loader.close();
        this.dialog.errorReport(error.status, error.statusText, error._body);

      }
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
(click)="upload(config.fileLocation)"
```

Never use `{{}}` together with `[foo]="..."` or `(bar)="..."`

`[]` and `()` already mark the attribute as Angular binding.
`{{}}` also only allows string binding (stringifies every value), while the others allow binding of object values.

Comment: oh that makes lots of sense, as `<input type="file" #fileInput accept="{{config.acceptedFiles}}">` this was working in the same file. I have used your suggestion which makes worked for me :D